# Combining two tables in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have made two tables. The first table holds the metadata of a file.

```
create table filemetadata (
id varchar(20) primary key ,
filename varchar(50),
path varchar(200),
size varchar(10),
author varchar(50)
) ;

+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| id    | filename    | path    | size | author  | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 1     | abc.txt     | c:\files| 2kb  | eric    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 2     | xyz.docx    | c:\files| 5kb  | john    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
| 3     | pqr.txt     |c:\files | 10kb | mike    | 
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+
```

The second table contains the "favourite" info about a particular file in the above table.

```
create table filefav (
fid varchar(20) primary key ,
id varchar(20),
favouritedby varchar(300),
favouritedtime varchar(10),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES filemetadata(id) 
) ;

+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| fid    | id   | favouritedby    | favouritedtime | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1      | 1    | ross            | 22:30          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 2      | 1    | josh            | 12:56          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3      | 2    | johny           | 03:03          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4      | 2    | sean            | 03:45          | 
+--------+------+-----------------+----------------+
```

here "id' is a foreign key.
The second table is showing which person has marked which document as his/her favourite.
Eg the file abc.txt represented by id = 1 has been marked favourite (see column favouritedby) by ross and josh.

so what i wanna do is to get a table/view which shows the info as following -

```
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+---------------+
| id    | filename    | path    | size | author  | favouritedby  |
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+---------------+
| 1     | abc.txt     | c:\files| 2kb  | eric    | ross, josh    |
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+---------------+
| 2     | xyz.docx    | c:\files| 5kb  | john    | johny, sean   |
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+---------------+
| 3     | pqr.txt     |c:\files | 10kb | mike    | NULL          |
+-------+-------------+---------+------+---------+---------------+
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Look into `JOIN`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JOIN` (from the top of my head, no checks done):

```
SELECT filemetadata.id, filename, path, size, author, GROUP_CONCAT(favouritedby) 
FROM filemetadata 
LEFT JOIN filefav ON filemetadata.id=filefav.id GROUP BY filemetadata.id
```

Comment: This is not working. I want all the names in the 'favouritedby' column who like a particular file (say abc.txt) represented by id=1 , in a single cell as ive shown in the example above.

Comment: @user2492264 that is what it should do. That's the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Could you elaborate your question with what you have now, what results you get and what you expect?

Comment: [You can see it here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-1YKc00rScsNHhRWXF1OXYwcHM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

`Select A.*,B.favouritedby FROM filemetadata A Left join (Select id,Group_Concat(favouritedby) from filefav  group by id) B ON A.`Id=B.Id

Answer (score -1):

Create a view that creates a UNION of the two tables:

```
CREATE VIEW filefavs AS
SELECT * FROM filemetadata 
UNION
SELECT * FROM filefav
```

Comment: No. He needs a `JOIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT`.